# error updating ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, updates

I've got an error "The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' no longer has a Release file" while running Update Manager.

Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged 18.04 as your release, but 'artful' is 17.10 which is the error you have provided (it's EOL, and post-eol the releases are moved).  That source shouldn't exist in a Ubuntu 18.04 system and needs removal.

Answer (score 0):

you should open "Software and Updates", go to the "Other Software" tab, then find that line and delete it. then exit Software and sources and allow soures to reload.

after that yupdates will work  once again.

Comment: Repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates' corresponds to “Recommended updates” option of “Other software” tab in “Software&Updates”. It seems to me that It shouldn’t be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I took advice about  [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1145897#tab-top) and created empty */etc/apt/sources.list* and set *“Software&Updates”* options.
Now system updates runs with no errors.
  But I have no idea where did previous release repository *'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates’* come from in */etc/apt/sources.list*. I didn't make any changes in */etc/apt/sources.list* and my previous system updates were successful.
I've found useful these articles.
[All series Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+series)
[Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)
[Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu/)
[Repositories/CommandLine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)